# VMware player gives Virtualization is incompatible with long mode on this platform

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

We've physical machine on which several virtual machines are installed using vm player. Now we are trying to install tool on one of these virtual machines, the tool require vm player, so we installed vmplayer 4.0.0 on the virtual machine. But the vmplayer gives error while installing tool like "Virtualization is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Without long mode support the virtual machine will not be able to run 64 bit code.

The visualization option on the physical machine is already enabled.

Any help on this.
[image: Issue]

Comment: Dang, [3k views and still](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-coders-worst-nightmare/answer/Jorge-Irun) no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get long mode working in Vmware by uninstalling Virtual PC.
No nesting or something, it simply started working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with VMWare Player on the host since the VT is not virtualized.

According to http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-support-for-nested-64bit.html?m=1 
you could do it with VMWare vSphere 5

Comment: Hi helb,
In the physical machine(host machine) the VT is turned on that's why we're capable of hosting several virtual machines(64bit). On one of these virtual machine we're agian installed vm player to install the tool. It's like nested VM!!.  Physical machine -> (Several VMs out which on One)->again vm -> tool(name of the tool is, DMX-h). So we're not getting where is the issue. the physical mahcine's VT is enabled.

Comment: @Pradi Sorry, I didn' get that from your Problem description. See my updated Answer.

Comment: I'll try the options which are mentioned in that link. Nest vm is the thing i'm trying here.  Physical machine is running several "virtual servers(some are 64bit servers)" with help of Vmware. On one of these virtual server i'm trying to install a tool called DMX-h which is giving me the error. Now you got me?